# Find the limit of such a sequence defined by recurrence (problematic induction because of $0$ in the denominator)

Tags: real-analysis, limits

So I need to find the limit of such a sequence defined by recurrence:

- $a_1 = \frac{1}{2}$
- $a_{n+1}= \frac{\sqrt{1+a_n^2}-1}{a_n}$

I have calculated some elements of that seqence and those are:

- $a_1 = 1$
- $a_2= \sqrt{2}-1 \approx 0,41$
- $a_3 = 1+ \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} = \frac{\sqrt{4-\sqrt{2}}-1}{\sqrt{2}-1} \approx 0,22$

So I know that the values of next elements of the sequence are falling. Next I wanted to do prove by induction that the limit = $0$ , but I can't put $0$ in the denominator. So what do I do?

Comment: Try to prove that there is a *lower bound* for the sequence. Let $a_n\geq0$, and prove that $a_{n+1}\geq0$.

Comment: Yeah, but the problem is, that then I need would then need to write: $a_{n+1}= \frac{\sqrt{1+a_n^2}-1}{a_n} \geq 0 \to a_{n+1}= \frac{\sqrt{1+0^2}-1}{0} \geq 0$ I can't write $0$ in the denominator.

Comment: I wrote an answer. Does it help?

Comment: Yes, you are great, man! Seriously, I am stunned how much I can learn just by asking questions on this forum. I really appreciate your help. If there is something I can do for you, tell me :D

Comment: By the way, you must be crazy smart if you are still a student

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now we prove that there is a *lower bound*.

Let $a_n>0$, then $$\sqrt{1+a^2_n}-1>\sqrt{1+0^2}-1=0$$ Since both $a_n$ and $\sqrt{1+a_n^2}-1$ are positive, we have $$a_{n+1}=\frac{\sqrt{1+a_n^2}-1}{a_n}>0$$

Hence the limit exists because of *Completeness of real numbers*. Let $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=L$, then the recurrence relation gives you $$L=\frac{\sqrt{1+L^2}-1}{L}$$

If $L\ne0$, then $$\begin{align}L^2=\sqrt{1+L^2}-1&\implies L^2+1=\sqrt{1+L^2}\\&\implies L^4+2L^2+1=L^2+1\\&\implies L^4+L^2=0\\&\implies L^2(L^2+1)=0\\&\implies L=0\end{align}$$
which is a contradiction. Therefore $L=0$.

Answer (score 1):

We can rearrange the given recurrence as $$a_{n+1}^2a_n+2a_{n+1}-a_n=0,$$ and take the positive solution of $a_{n+1}.$ I will prove that the sequence is bounded and monotonically decreasing by manipulating this new recurrence relation. Note that $$2a_{n+1}=a_n-a_{n+1}^2a_n= a_n(1-a_{n+1})(1+a_{n+1})\gt0$$ implies that $1-a_{n+1}\gt0,$ and hence $$1\gt a_{n+1}\gt 0$$ for all $n$ (including $0$). Also $$a_n-a_{n+1}=a_{n+1}+a_{n+1}^2a_n= a_{n+1}(1+a_{n+1}a_n)\gt 0$$ implies that $a_n\gt a_{n+1},$ and therefore the sequence is decreasing. **Now** by the (bounded) monotone convergent theorem, this sequence must have a limit $l$ in non-negative real numbers. Find it by solving $$l^3+2l-l=l(l^2+1)=0.$$